# Is there a way to snooze the reminder for a calendar event on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

Is it possible to snooze a reminder for a calendar event when the reminder shows up? I have my calendar set up through an exchange server and would like a snooze feature so I can be reminded of the event 2 or 4 hours after the original notification. If this is not possible is there a good app for recurring events with push notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported by the default calendar app at the moment. An app called [Calendar Alarm](http://itunes.apple.com/app/calendar-alarm/id367803799) from the App Store might be what you're looking for. Its listed features include:

> - Works seamlessly together with all
>     iPhone supported calendars (Google
>     Calendar, CalDAV, Outlook, Exchange,
>     iCal).
> - Snooze function with intervals of your choice.

Comment: This app is not available (maybe just for my region). Looking for alternatives. Coming from Android, where I had "Event Alarm Reminder for Google Calendar".